# Grails hasMany: when child is updated, parent's version changes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

I am using Grails and am quite surprised by the way `hasMany` relationships work. I have a typical `hasMany` relationship where the parent id is in the child table. When I insert a child and try to save it through the parent object, the parent object's version id gets incremented. My question is: Why should the parent's version id change when there is a change only in the child object?

```
class Parent { 
    static hasMany = [children: child]
}

class child {
    string name 
    Parent parent
    static belongsTo = [Parent]
}

def p = Parent.get(1)
p.addToChildren(new Child(name: "Roy"))
p.save()
```

The version of `p` gets incremented from 0 to 1. Is there any way I can avoid this in Grails?

Due to the change in version ID of the parent I get a stale object exception. Any help?

Comment: In my mind, the Parent object _has_ changed, because it got a new child. My 2c worth

Comment: Soren is correct - a property has changed (analagous to adding one char to a String property) so the whole object is considered changed. This is a Hibernate thing and not a Grails thing.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to [disable optimistic locking](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.7%20Optimistic%20Locking%20and%20Versioning) for your domain object.

#### Update

Or try [to search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895460/hibernate-versioning-parent-entity).

Comment: is there an other solution? I need to have a version id column in the table