# OneToMany Mapping version update on parent entity when child is modified

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring boot with JPA. I have two questions

1. I have two entities Order and OrderLineItems. I am saving the Order entity using `orderDao.save()`, Which saves line items as well. When I update line-items, only the line-items version is getting updated. I want to update the version of the parent. I don't have OrderLineItemsDao.
2. All our Entities extend BaseEntity. It has the `lastModifiedAt` column which is annotated with `@UpdateTimestamp` which is making all the records dirty. I am planning to remove it, is it fine and update it manually? Or do we have any other way to stop the unnecessary updates to DB?

Comment: #1 isn't a question. Did you mean to ask how you update the version in Order when only a child/OrderLineItem changes? This isn't part of JPA but some providers have solutions (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724804/496099 ) or manual options (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895460/hibernate-versioning-parent-entity ). For #2 - why not? I am not familiar with @UpdateTimestamp or when it executes, but maybe try JPA's preUpdate event, which are required to only be called when there are changes (it is dirty).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the explicit approach that Chris mentioned, which is to force incrementing the optimistic lock version of that `Order` entity.

```
entityManager.lock(parent, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
```